# Apache HttpClient: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException

Tags: java, apache, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x

I see a lot of threads on this, but I am unable to find a solution for my environment. I am running a jar on z/OS UNIX shell, and I'm using HttpClient's Fluent API to POST to a REST service. The code works just fine for HTTP, however, for SSL, it gives me a cert error.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=MASTER_CERTAUTH_CERTIFICATE, T=MASTER_CERT_for_RACF, OU=MyOrg, O=MSTR, L=MyLocation, ST=MyState, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.jsse2.o.a(o.java:8)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:549)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:355)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:130)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:135)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:368)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.s(kb.java:442)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:136)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:495)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.h(SSLSocketImpl.java:223)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:724)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:81)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:261)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:118)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:314)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:357)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:218)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:194)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:85)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request.execute(Request.java:143)
    at com.myproject.utils.helpers.HTTP.send(HTTP.java:114)
    at com.myproject.utils.helpers.HTTP.send(HTTP.java:49)
    at com.myproject.utils.operations.ActionManager.loadMedguides(ActionManager.java:66)
    at com.myproject.utils.main.PatientSafetyUtils.main(PatientSafetyUtils.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
```

How can I install the cert on the server (all I have is the URL, and the server does not have `openssl`). Or is there a way I can bypass this error completely? I don't really care about SSL as the REST webservice is also hosted on the same Mainframe.

Comment: if its working on HTTP why are you asking? why not just use HTTP?

Comment: Yes, it is an IBM mainframe. I don't have much info on the REST service, other than the fact that it is not written in Java. And I am running a jar from the java command line from z/OS shell.

There is a non-https endpoint as well (which works just fine) but before moving my project to production, I need to start using the https endpoint.

Comment: so the issue is your outbound connection is not trusted, you need to get someone issue you a certificate who maintains the production environment, if all applications use HTTPS this should be a standard process wherever your production environment is. Thats the whole point of HTTPS, trusted connections with well defined users and certificates.

Comment: This is a new system, so the standard cert installations don't work for this. Is there a way I can write a custom SSL validator for this request?

Comment: i do not think that would solve your issue. the issue is trust between client and server, the server is rejecting your request and therefore you cannot connect with your client.

Comment: I thought it was the other way around. From what I see from different threads, I need to have the client trust the server.

Comment: well thats true too, you need to trust the server as well... if its two way SSL both sides need to trust. you can import the server certificate using openssl ill post below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the server certificate you can use open SSL to do so:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect host.host:9999 </dev/null
```

The server certificate is the first certificate returned, and will be PEM formatted. The CA certificate is the final certificate returned, and is also PEM formatted.

then you can import them PEMs to a JKS and configure httpclient to use that JKS. for more info about PEM to JKS http://www.agentbob.info/agentbob/79-AB.html

Comment: The output contains more than one certificates as a "certificate chain", in addition to the chunks of -- BEGIN CERFICATE -- and -- END CERTIFICATE --. Should I simply dump the output of this to a .pem file? It also contains SSL session details in the output.

Comment: you should put them into a PEM file without the session info or the intermediate certifiates i believe